# Different version in the GetCapabilities of WFS?

Tags: wfs, getcapabilities

In the GetCapabilities of some WFS, I can see two versions mentioned.

```
<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>2.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
<ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.1.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
```

Does it mean that the different versions are fully supported by the service?

The differences between V 2.0.0 and V 1.1.0 are not big, V 2.0.0 has more query available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean that the different versions are fully supported by the service?

It means that both versions are supported.

You have to read the specific GetCapabilities responses to determine which of the WFS features/methods/operation are actually supported, it doesn't imply any *fullness*

The differences between the versions are more than extra query functionality though, you just need to decide which version you need to use based on your client/user needs.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that under OperationsMetadata it is possible to check what operations are available. I just sounded strange to keep the old version available since 2.0.X is supporting mostof the operations.

Comment: As much as anything, it comes as default with the software rather than being an implementation choice of the service provider.  So if you have an old service and you upgrade the software, then all the old clients accessing your service continue working, and even if you create a new service, not all the existing client software might be able to handle the new version...